# Run native mongodb query with mongodb java driver

Tags: json, mongodb, bson

I want to execute CRUD operations with java like`updateOne()`,`updateMany()` or `deleteMany()` etc. But when I want to run with operators like `$set`, `$unset` I have to import new classes like `Updates` or create nested `Document` objects. I want to insert JSON query as native Mongodb uses. Ex: 
`myCollection.updateOne(Json_String_filter,Query_with_operoters_like_$set_as_Json_string);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Document.parse(String json)` from `org.bson.Document`. It returns Document object. Here is an example from [Official MongoDb tutorial](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents/).

Original:

```
{
     $set: { "size.uom": "cm", status: "P" },
     $currentDate: { lastModified: true }
   }
```

You can run in java as:

```
collection.updateMany(new Document(),Document.parse("{\n" +
                "     $set: { \"size.uom\": \"cm\", status: \"P\" },\n" +
                "     $currentDate: { lastModified: true }\n" +
                "   }"));
```

Comment: That was the way I looking for.