# MongoDB native query with Aggreagtion to query in Java

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, spring-mongodb, spring-mongo

I have native Mongo query

```
[
{
    $match: {
        createdById: "5c3cac81989a8469d435f3b2"
    }
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: "$uID",
        latest: {
            $max: "$latest"
        },
        createdById: {
            $first: "$createdById"
        }
    }
}
]
```

**Reposiroty**

```
Page<NetworkObject> findByCreatedById(String userId, Pageable pageable);
```

I tried such like this

```
@Query(value = "[ {'$match': {'createdById': ?#{[0]} }}, {'$group': {'_id': '$uID', 'latest': {'$max': '$latest'}, 'createdById': {'$first': '$createdById'}}}]"
Page<NetworkObject> findByCreatedById(String userId, Pageable pageable);
```

but i have an error

```
org.bson.BsonInvalidOperationException: readStartDocument can only be called when CurrentBSONType is DOCUMENT, not when CurrentBSONType is ARRAY.
```

seems that i must be changet to Aggregation query but i dont worked with it yet.

**Update**
Create Aggregation

```
Aggregation aggregation = newAggregation(match(Criteria.where("createdById").is(userId)),
                group(fields("uID").and("latest","$latest")
                        .and("createdById","$createdById"))
                        .max("$latest").as("latest")
                        .first("$createdById").as("createdById"));
        AggregationResults<NetworkObject> results = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation,"NetworkObject",NetworkObject.class);
        List<NetworkObject> objects = Optional.of(results.getMappedResults()).get();
```

But it returns me all collection elements by createdById.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50535193/run-native-mongodb-query-with-mongodb-java-driver